# Java Tic Tac Toe Minimax Bug

Tags: java, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

Have tried debugging my MiniMax code but can't seem to find the problem here. The main method is `evalGame()`, which returns 1 for a win, -1 for a loss and 0 for a tie. Are there any obvious errors I have made in the MiniMax algorithm?

```
package tictactoe;

import static tictactoe.Player.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MinimaxTTT {

    private Player[] board = new Player[9];
    private static Player player = X;

    public MinimaxTTT() {
        Arrays.fill(board, E);
        player = X;
    }

    public MinimaxTTT(Player[] b, Player p) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            board[i] = b[i];
        }
        player = p;
    }

    public static boolean checkWin(Player[] b, Player p) {
        if((b[0]==p&&b[1]==p&&b[2]==p) 
            || (b[0]==p&&b[3]==p&&b[6]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[1]==p&&b[2]==p)
            || (b[1]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[7]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[1]==p&&b[2]==p)
            || (b[2]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[6]==p)
            || (b[2]==p&&b[5]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[3]==p&&b[6]==p)
            || (b[3]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[5]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[2]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[6]==p)
            || (b[3]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[5]==p)
            || (b[1]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[7]==p)
            || (b[2]==p&&b[5]==p&&b[8]==p) 
            || (b[3]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[5]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[3]==p&&b[6]==p)
            || (b[2]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[6]==p)
            || (b[6]==p&&b[7]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[6]==p&&b[7]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[1]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[7]==p)
            || (b[2]==p&&b[5]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[6]==p&&b[7]==p&&b[8]==p)
            || (b[0]==p&&b[4]==p&&b[8]==p)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkTie(Player[] b) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(b[i] == E) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean gameOver(Player[] b) {
        return checkTie(b) || checkWin(b, X) || checkWin(b, O);
    }

    private static int maxOfArray(int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];
        for (int i : a)
            if (max < i)
                max = i;
        return max;
    }

    private static int minOfArray(int[] a) {
        int min = a[0];
        for (int i : a)
            if (min > i)
                min = i;
        return min;
    }

    private static int getEmptyNumber(Player[] b) {
        int spaces = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(b[i] == E)
                spaces++;
        }
        return spaces;
    }

    private static int evalGame(Player[] b, Player p, Player currentP) {
        if(gameOver(b)) {
            if(checkWin(b, p)) {
                return 1;
            } else if(checkWin(b, p == X ? O : X)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            int[] arrayEval = new int[getEmptyNumber(b)];
            for(int i = 0; i < getEmptyNumber(b); i++) {
                arrayEval[i] = evalGame(possibleBoards(b, currentP)[i], p, currentP == X ? O : X);
            }
            if(currentP == p) {
                return maxOfArray(arrayEval);
            } else {
                return minOfArray(arrayEval);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Player[][] possibleBoards(Player[] b, Player p) {
        Player[][] toReturn = new Player[getEmptyNumber(b)][9];
        int spaces = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(b[i] == E) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    toReturn[spaces][j] = b[j];
                }
                toReturn[spaces][i] = p;
                spaces++;
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player[] p = new Player[9];
        Arrays.fill(p, E);
        p[1] = X;
        System.out.println(evalGame(p, O, O));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any errors. What are `X` and `O` defined as (what data type) in the `checkWin` calls and such? I'm guessing they're constants that you didn't post the declarations of?

Comment: @mbomb007 And E in getEmptyNumber()

Comment: @hfontanez In method evalGame(): `if(checkWin(b, p)) {
            return 1;
        } else if(checkWin(b, p == X ? O : X)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }` I think `return 0` means that it's a draw.

Comment: Besides all that, how is this even running ? Where are the moves ? How can we debug this on our own ?

Comment: What error does the program throw, or how is they game not working as expected?

Comment: How is `checkWin` defined?

Comment: @mbomb007 X, O and E are constants int he enum Player. E represents an empty square.

Comment: I see a problem: `gameOver()` should check if there are any squares on the matrix that are not filled. It should not check to see who wins.

Also, you check for a draw, and if that returns false, there is a winner, you don't need two calls to `checkWin()`. This method can return (for instance) false if X wins and true otherwise. Does that make sense?

Comment: @mbomb007 There are no exceptions, just seemingly random unexpected results. Will edit and post entire class, give me a second

Comment: @hfontanez gameOver() is a boolean which returns true if someone has won or if it is a tie (i.e. no squares remaining). Not really a big issue im worried about, it would do the smae thing while saving maybe 2 lines of code.

Comment: You still haven't told us, what your problem is.

Comment: This is how I would do it: Initialize your 2D array with null character. Your `gameOver` method returns true if no element in the array contains the null character. To check win

arr[?][0], arr[?][0],and arr[?][0] must have the same character, OR
arr[0][?], arr[1][?],and arr[2][?] must have the same character, OR
arr[0][0], arr[1][1],and arr[2][2] must have the same character, OR
arr[0][2], arr[1][1],and arr[2][0] must have the same character. Something like that...

Comment: This shouldn't fix anything, but your `checkWin()` method has many duplicate lines of the game board checked. Note that there are only 8 possible winning 3-in-a-rows: 3 horizontal, 3 vertical, and 2 diagonal.

Comment: @mbomb007, do you agree that the `gameOver()` method should only check for empty squares? I think my explanation above is how the methods should be constructed.

Comment: @hfontanez ok thanks for the input, but not really what the question was. Not worried about efficiency atm

Comment: Yeah. Maybe `if(gameOver(b)) {` could even be removed. It's doing the same check like 4 or more times. I don't think this is the root of the problem though. The program would be easier to understand if instead the Player had a property which was set to either `X` or `O`, then you pass in both the board AND the player to check for empty squares or a win. Then when checking for a win, you can use `p.letter` or whatever.

Comment: @FraserPrice, this is not so much about efficiency. You are having problems debugging your own code. My suggestion is to simplify it first, then fix it. Your main problem is that your solution does not observe the Single-Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since looked over my code and realised I made a mistake while debugging. The working, edited code is below for anyone who is interested

```
package tictactoe;

import static tictactoe.Player.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MinimaxTTT {

    private Player[] board = new Player[9];
    private Player player = X;

    public MinimaxTTT() {
        Arrays.fill(board, E);
        player = X;
    }

    public MinimaxTTT(Player[] b, Player p) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            board[i] = b[i];
        }
        player = p;
    }

    public Player[] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(Player[] b) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            board[i] = b[i];
        }
    }

    public void setSquare(int i, Player p) {
        board[i] = p;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player p) {
        player = p;
    }

    public void switchPlayers() {
        player = player == X ? O : X;
    }

    public boolean checkWin(Player[] b, Player p) {
        if(b[0] == p && b[1] == p && b[2] == p 
            || b[3] == p && b[4] == p && b[5] == p
            || b[6] == p && b[7] == p && b[8] == p
            || b[0] == p && b[3] == p && b[6] == p
            || b[1] == p && b[4] == p && b[7] == p
            || b[2] == p && b[5] == p && b[8] == p
            || b[0] == p && b[4] == p && b[8] == p
            || b[2] == p && b[4] == p && b[6] == p) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkTie(Player[] b) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(b[i] == E) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean gameOver(Player[] b) {
        return checkTie(b) || checkWin(b, X) || checkWin(b, O);
    }

    private int maxOfArray(int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];
        for (int i : a)
            if (max < i)
                max = i;
        return max;
    }

    private int minOfArray(int[] a) {
        int min = a[0];
        for (int i : a)
            if (min > i)
                min = i;
        return min;
    }

    private int getEmptyNumber(Player[] b) {
        int spaces = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(b[i] == E)
                spaces++;
        }
        return spaces;
    }

    private int findIndex(int[] is, int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < is.length; i++) {
            if(is[i] == n)
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int[] evalGame(Player[] b, Player p, Player currentP, int depth) {
        int[] toReturn = new int[2];
        if(gameOver(b)) {
            if(checkWin(b, p)) {
                toReturn[1] = 10 + depth;
                return toReturn;
            } else if(checkWin(b, p == X ? O : X)) {
                toReturn[1] = depth - 10;
                return toReturn;
            } else {
                toReturn[1] = 0;
                return toReturn;
            }
        } else {
            depth += 1;
            int[] arrayEval = new int[getEmptyNumber(b)];
            for(int i = 0; i < getEmptyNumber(b); i++) {
                arrayEval[i] = evalGame(possibleBoards(b, currentP)[i], p, currentP == X ? O : X, depth)[1];
            }
            if(currentP == p) {
                int position = findIndex(arrayEval, maxOfArray(arrayEval));
                int base = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    if(b[i] == E) {
                        if(base == position) {
                            toReturn[0] = i;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            base++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                toReturn[1] = maxOfArray(arrayEval);
                return toReturn;
            } else {
                toReturn[1] = minOfArray(arrayEval);
                return toReturn;
            }
        }
    }

    public Player[][] possibleBoards(Player[] b, Player p) {
        Player[][] toReturn = new Player[getEmptyNumber(b)][9];
        int spaces = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(b[i] == E) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    toReturn[spaces][j] = b[j];
                }
                toReturn[spaces][i] = p;
                spaces++;
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public Player[] move() {
        if(!gameOver(board)) {
            board[evalGame(board, player, player, 0)[0]] = player;
        }
        return board;
    }
}
```